# How do I retain grads and also change device type in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

When I change my input variable from CPU to cuda, it loses all its grad and also loses its `is_leaf` status. How do I circumvent this? I want to keep the gradients and also change it to another device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A leaf tensor is one which has its `requires_grad` attribute set to `True`. When you do any out-of-place operation on a tensor the resulting tensor is no longer a leaf tensor. This includes creating a copy of the tensor on a different device using `.to(device)`, `.cuda()`, or `.cpu()`. The recommended way to set the `requires_grad` attribute of an existing tensor is to use the in-place [`Tensor.requires_grad_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.requires_grad_) method. If you want the tensor on the GPU to be the leaf node then you will need to set `requires_grad` **after** copying to the desired device.

For example

```py
input = input.to('cuda')
input.requires_grad_(True)   # need to set requires_grad after copying to GPU
```

or a little more concisely

```py
input = input.to('cuda').requires_grad_(True)
```